# Fill color in ggplot with multiple conditions

Tags: if-statement, ggplot2, subset, fill

I am trying to make some plots with my data and I´m having some trouble.

I want to maka a plot where all the "testers" have the same color (gray) and the other individuals (A, B, C, D, E) have different colors.

My data looks something like this:

```
pr<-read_xlsx("pr.xlsx")


pr<- data.frame(Code= c("TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
        MEAN_RIN=c(2, 3, 1.5, 2.3, 1.2, 0.6, 2, 1.4))
testers<- c("TEST1", "TEST2", "TEST3")

ggplot(aes(x=reorder(Code, MEAN_RIN), y=MEAN_RIN), data=pr)+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill= Code))+
  scale_fill_manual(values= ifelse(pr$Code %in% testers, "gray15", hue_pal()(10)))
```

This is the output I get=
[image]

Very far from desired one..

I also tried subsetting the data, but the order of the columns is changed.

```
ggplot(aes(x=reorder(Code, MEAN_RIN), y=MEAN_RIN), data=pr)+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="gray15", data= subset(pr, Code %in% testers))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill= Code), data= subset(pr, !Code %in% testers))+
  scale_fill_manual(values= ifelse(pr$Code %in% testers, "gray15", hue_pal()(10)))
```

[image]

Someone knows how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to change where the `ifelse` is being used, use it to make a new column in the dataframe with the colours you want to use, and then plot:

```
pr <- pr %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    # mutate a new column with the ifelse 
    fill_col = ifelse(Code %in% testers, "grey15", hue_pal()(10))
  )

ggplot(aes(x=reorder(Code, MEAN_RIN), y=MEAN_RIN), data=pr)+
  # fill directly with the colour column
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(fill= fill_col)) + 
  # this command makes it clear for R to use the colours in the column
  scale_fill_identity()
```

And now all the test columns are `grey15`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Besides using `scale_fill_identity` as in the approach bay @colebrookson a second option would be to create a manual fill palette as a named vector and set the fill colors to `"gray15"` for the `testers` categories:

```r
library(ggplot2)

pr$Code <- reorder(pr$Code, pr$MEAN_RIN)
pal_fill <- scales::hue_pal()(10)
names(pal_fill) <- levels(pr$Code)

pal_fill[names(pal_fill) %in% testers] <- "gray15"

ggplot(aes(x = Code, y = MEAN_RIN), data = pr) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = Code)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal_fill)
```

[image]